# Proving that an integral is a holomorphic function

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, analytic-functions

Let $U\in \mathbb C$. Let $f:U\to\mathbb C$ be analytic on $U$ and continuous on the boundary of $U$. I want to prove that, for each $a\in U$, and sufficiently small $r>0$, 
$$
g(w)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|z-a|=r}\frac{zf'(z)}{f(z)-w}dz
$$
defines a holomorphic function.

My attempt: Assume for a moment that $f$ is injective (not actually valid). Using the substitution $x=f(z)$, we get
$$
g(w)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|f^{-1}(x)-a|=r}\frac{f^{-1}(x)}{x-w}dx=f^{-1}(w)
$$
by Cauchy integration formula, since $f^{-1}$ is analytic (because $f'(z)\neq0$).

Is this valid? I feel something missing. **For example, I have not addressed the condition "sufficiently small r".** What's wrong?

Comment: (i) $f$ need not be injective. (ii) if $r$ is not sufficiently small, the circle $|x-a|=r$ may not lie in $U$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown That's why I say "for a moment". Can you offer a proper answer?

Comment: The question is not stated properly. Where is $g$ suppose to be analytic? If $f(z)=z$ then  $g(w)$ is not defined for $|w-a|=r$ so we cannot expect $g$ to be analytic on the whole of $U$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Could you write an answer?  At least $g$ should be analytic on $U$ if it is injective.

Comment: Whatever $r$ you take you can have points $z$ where $f(z)=w$ in which case the integral over  the circle is not defined. The best approach is to follow the answer below by Robert Israel. You will get a holomorphic function  on $\{w\in U: f(z)\neq w $ for any $z$ on the circle $|z-a|=r \}$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy So you are saying that this question on my book is wrong, and we should instead assign different $r$ to each $z$, so we should write $r(z)$ instead of just $r$. Is it valid this way?

Comment: Yes, as stated, the result in the book is wrong. For a given $w \in U$ we can find $r$ such that $f(z)\neq w$ for all $z$ with $|z-a|=r$ (unless $f$ is a constant). This because the roots of the equation $f(z)=w$ have no limit points.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy So in this correct case, I can just apply the argument I give in the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $n$ be the order of the zero of $f(z)-f(a)$ at $z=a$.

$$f(z)- f(a)= f^{(n)}(a) (z-a)^n+O((z-a)^{n+1})$$

For $r$ small enough then $f(z)-f(a)-w, |z-a|=r$ doesn't vanish on $|w| < R= \frac12 |f^{(n)}(a)| r^n$ so that $$g(f(a)+w)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|z-a|=r}\frac{zf'(z)}{f(z)-f(a)-w}dz$$ is analytic on $|w| < R$.

Iff $n=1$ then $g(w) = f^{-1}(w)$ (proving the latter is locally analytic). If $n=2$ then the substitution $u = f(z)$ in the integral transforms the simple loop $|z-a| = r$ into a double loop around $f(a)$.

You can use the residue theorem to express $g(f(a)+w)$ in term of $f^{-1}$.

Comment: I wrote everything, what do you mean ? Gluing together the local branches of $f^{-1}$ is complicated, local analyticity gives global analyticity on simply connected sets. Otherwise remove the points where $n > 1$ and take simply connected subsets $U$ and show $\int_{|z-a|=r} = \int_{\partial U}$ to obtain the global branches

Answer (score 0):

EDITED:

More generally, let $\mu$ be a complex (finite) measure on a measurable space $X$, $\varphi$ a measurable function on $X$, and $V$ an open subset of $\mathbb C$ that does not intersect $\varphi(X)$.  Then

$$ g(z) = \int_X \frac{d\mu(x)}{\varphi(x) - z}$$
is analytic in $V$.  You can prove this using Morera's theorem.

In the OP's case, $V = \mathbb C \backslash f(\Gamma_r)$ where $\Gamma_r$ is the circle $|z-a| = r$.  Note that for any $w \ne f(a)$, you can take $r$ small enough that $w \in V$.

Comment: I think OP has to be told that $g$ is not defined and analytic on the whole of $U$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Aha. My $U$ is assumed not to intersect $\phi(X)$, but this is not necessarily the same as the $U$ in the original question. I should edit.