# Compact surface with closed 1-form

Tags: complex-geometry, elliptic-curves, riemann-surfaces

Why a compact surface with closed a nowhere vanishes complex 1-form, giving $T^{2}$?

Comment: If $X$ is a compact Riemann surface and $df$ is an exact meromorphic one-form then integrating $df$ gives an holomorphic map to the Riemann sphere so by Riemann-Hurwitz $df$ has $2g-2$ more zeros than poles (with $g$ the number of holes in $X$). $\deg(Div(\omega)) = \deg(Div(g))+\deg(Div(df))=0+(2g-2)$ stays true for any meromorphic one-form $\omega = g df$. Thus if $\omega$ is an holomorphic one-form with $Div(\omega) = 0$ then $g=1$ and $X$ is an elliptic curve. I don't know if something similar can be said about harmonic one-forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X$ a compact Riemann surface and $\omega$ a non-zero holomorphic one-form having no zeros (that is in every local chart $\omega = f(z)dz$ with $f$ locally  analytic with no zero).

Let $$F(p) = \int_{p_0}^p \omega$$
(in local chart $F(p) =F(a)+ \int_a^p f(z)dz$)

Let $U$ be the universal cover of $X$ : that is $U$ is the Riemann surface obtained from the set of curves $\Gamma : p_0 \to p$ in $X$ modulo homotopy.

$U$ is topologically a simply connected domain.

Locally $F'$ doesn't vanish so $F$ is locally biholomorphic, since $U,F(U)$ are  simply connected domains then $F$ is biholomorphic $U \to F(U)$.

Pick some closed-loops $\gamma_1,\ldots,\gamma_J$ generating the fundamental group $\pi_1(X)$.

Let $L = \{ \sum_{j=1}^J c_j \int_{\gamma_j} \omega, c_j \in \Bbb{Z}\}$.

This makes clear $F(U) = \Bbb{C}$.

The injectivity of $F : U \to \Bbb{C}$ means $L$ must be a lattice.

And hence $F$ is biholomorphic $X \to \Bbb{C}/L$.

Comment: You are the best! Thank you reuns

Comment: Why $dF$ is locally nonzero implies that F is locally biholomorphic? It is like submersion and local diffeomorphism in real case?

Comment: Locally the inverse has an explicit expression showing it is analytic https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3271272/276986 equivalently see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem The difficulty is to show those local inverses glue together to form a global inverse because we are on a simply connected domain

Comment: and that the image is simply connected (see how the inverse fails to be globally analytic with $\exp : \Bbb{C} \to \Bbb{C}^*$)